# div disappearing in IE7

Tags: css, html, internet-explorer-7, html-lists

I have a problem with a div in IE7, it's disappearing and I don't understand why.
I already tried to add zoom:1 and overflow: hidden as someone suggested but it is not working.

The div is inside an unordered list (floated left) as the last element, floated right.

This is the HTML

```
<div id="top_menu">
    <ul id="dropmenu">
        <li>menu item1</li>
        <li>menu item2</li>
        ...
     </ul>
    <div class="lang">content</div>
</div><!-- end top menu -->
```

This is the CSS

```
  #top_menu                     {width:900px;font-size:13px; }
    #top_menu ul#dropmenu           {width:630px; height:28px; margin:0px; padding:0px; list-style:none; float:left; }
    #top_menu ul#dropmenu li        {float:left;display:block;}
    .clearfix                       {display: inline-block;}  /* for IE/Mac */

    #top_menu .lang { width: 120px; color:#fff; margin:4px 10px 0 0; float: right; }
    #top_menu .lang a{ color:#ff8601; }
    #top_menu .lang a:hover{ color:#fff; }
```

Thanks for your help

EDIT: I included the html and removed url to avoid client complaints.

Comment: Please post your html code. It makes it easier to help you.

Comment: he's posted the url. is there any need to post any code?

Comment: since the website is online and I provided the link, it's easier if you check code on the website. thanks

Comment: @BizNuge - one good reason for posting code is that SO is intended as a resource for future reference as well as answering the question at hand. Without the relevant information, it makes it hard to follow what the problem was, if someone comes across the question at a later date.

Comment: @Spudley - Fair point! Taken into consideration for the future!

Comment: @Spudley, you're totally right, that's why after the problem was solved I posted the code, for future reference!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add `.clearfix` to `div#top_menu` and add `height: 24px;` to `div.lang`

That fixed all the menu problems for me.

### edit

...and probably don't use absolute positioning to solve layout issues.

Comment: thanks. this works, anyway I solved with absolute positioning.

Comment: @andycap I added an edit before I saw this comment.  Although I'm sure it works, `absolute` positioning is usually a poor solution.  There are some cases where it's right, but it takes the element out of the regular flow of the HTML rendering, which is usually more problems than it's worth in the long run.

Comment: you're right, it's a more elegant solution, however I tried it and it's not working for me. This is what i get http://i52.tinypic.com/2z7eog0.png thanks

Comment: @andycap make sure `ul#dropmenu` has `float:left;` as it was before, and make sure `div.lang` has `float:right;` as it was before.

Comment: bam! simple and elegant. Thank again!

Answer (score 2):

i'm on IE9 now, but putting this site into "Compatibility View" seems to show the issue too.

The last entry in the main menu [ul] seems to extend all the way to the right of the element. This appears in markup before the .lang div so I wouldn't expect it to be covering it up...

Have you maybe tried putting the .lang element into "position:absolute" and then seeing if it shows up, (obviously assuming the parent element of it is positioned relatively). After that maybe try absolute with a top of 20px or so and see if it shows up then.

Good Luck!

**UPDATE**

Hang on a tick there. your .lang div is inside the [ul] element so is actually incorrectly positioned, since the only element allowed as a child of a [ul] is a [li].

Why not try taking this div out of the list and have it instead, just outside, as a child of the #top_menu element....?

That might work!

Comment: Thanks BizNuge, yes I've tried to put absolute and the div is showing under the bar where was expected to be. Also the style (color, hover) is the one of the containing ul and not the one I specified.

Comment: Ok shame on me, this makes sense! But now won't stay in the same line and goes under the top_menu div. Tried to float:left the ul and right the .lang but the menu background disappears.

Comment: the same happens with display:inline on the [ul]

Comment: If you take the .lang element outside of the ul, and place it within the #top_menu div, after the ul, give it position:relative, and make the #top_menu position:relative, does that have any effect. if not, maybe try also giving the .lang z-index:1000 to see if it's just appearing behind. Worth a shot perhaps. glad to hear you got a bit further with it anyway man! Just read rockerest's post about not doing absolute for fixing this... he makes a fair point to be honest, but the cludge might at least let you see what's happening!

Comment: Sorry to spam post here.... Why not simply make the ul NOT be 900px wide (maybe 750/800), then you can float it left within #top_menu, and float .lang right within the same element...?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is relevant to your situation, but some versions of IE will throw away empty divs; if the div doesn't contain anything, adding something like &nbsp; will force it to exist.